# Catching String returned from REST in angular. I have already implemented it but I want to know if it's done the right way

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

In Angular Service.ts:

```
changePriority(ticket : TicketDetails) {
    return this.http.put("api/serviceEngineer/updatePriority", ticket, {responseType : 'text'})
  }

I declared the Http Client in the following way using a constructor:

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
```

In this way Iam catching the string returned from REST in angular but I got to know from a friend that it is not the right way to do so and I want to know why exactly. He was saying it would always be active unlike an Observable. Any help would be extremely appreciable. Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry and please consider it being a POST request and not a PUT. Thank you again

Comment: What do you mean by "active" in: "it would always be *active* unlike an Observable". Also, how did you declare `http`? If it's an HttpClient then it already returns an Observable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply MondKin and I have edited my post, please check again. And so if it's a HttpClient then it always returns an Observable? Sorry if this is a stupid question but I have just recently started my career in Spring and Angular. And by active I mean will it be only called when the consumer subscribes the method?

Comment: Yes, it always returns Observables. If you want a Promise you have to invoke `toPromise` in the returned observable. Check a tutorial about HttpClient, like this one: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/

Comment: The link you have shared looks very helpful and I will definitely check it, Thank you @MondKin and also so what's happening in that method is usually if we don't mention a type, it would take it as an Observable<Object> which will be converted to string because of the Response type I mentioned below. Is that right?

Comment: No. Still you'll be getting an observable.  {responseType : 'text'} means that response is of text type instead of the default type which is json.

Comment: Thank you for all the help MondKin and Anand Bhushan.

Comment: If you want to specify a return type you can use `this.http.put<MyClass>(...)` but that makes more sense when using the default json parsing, not when specifying `text` as the type.